# How to run "rails new.." from inside an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a rails engine that exposes a command called `myengine create`.  That command generates a full Rails application with `myengine` already integrated into it.  The command calls `rails new ...` to generate the app.  Everything works fine as long as I execute this command **outside** of the engine folder.  However, if I execute it inside the engine folder, it breaks because it runs the `bin/rails` command inside the engine, instead of the regular `rails` command that is installed on the system.  The `bin/rails` inside the engine folder is configured to work with engines so it doesn't have a `rails new` command.

I'm trying to write automated tests that run the `myengine create` command from within the engine to validate the output.  If I'm anywhere inside the engine directory though, calling `rails new` fails.

I've tried specifying the exact `rails` command like `"/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rails new ..."`, but this doesn't work.

The only workaround I've been able to come up with is to build the application outside of the engine folder by using `Dir.chdir` or Thor's `inside` method.  I can test against it there, or even move the newly generated app folder back into my `spec/` folder.  It works, but it feels sloppy.  There must be some way to generate a new from inside an engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, I ended up enhancing my command to rename `bin/rails` to a temporary new name before it tried to run `rails new`.  Then the command renamed it back once `rails new` completed.